# disable div id after its click

Tags: jquery

```
         <style type="text/css">
      #thebutton { width: 100px; background-color: #eee; text-align: center;      
                 padding: 10px; cursor: pointer; }              
       #thebutton.activated    { font-weight: bold;}
       #thebutton.hovering     { color: Blue; }

 #thebox { background-color: #eee; position:relative; width: 300px; height: 200px; 
               padding: 10px; top: 5px; display: none;}
        </style>

   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {

    $("#thebutton").click(function () {
         var currentValue ;


    $.ajax({

        type:       "post",
        url:        "checklikes",

        //data:           "user="+name.val(),
        success:    function(msg)
                    {
                      $("#replies").html(msg)
            .fadeIn("fast");
                         currentValue=parseInt(msg)+1;

                        $("#test").html(currentValue)
            .fadeIn("fast");
                             var data1= $("#test").text();


              $.ajax({

        type:       "post",
        url:        "checkupdate",

        data:           "user="+data1,
        success:    function(msg)
                    {
                      $("#t").html(msg)
            .fadeIn("fast");
                             $("#thebutton").toggleClass("activated");
            $("#thebutton").hasClass("activated") ? $("#thebox").fadeIn():
                 $("#thebox").fadeOut();                  

           $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');

                    }




    });
                    }




    });
        });
        });
    <body>
    <div id="thebutton">Click me!</div>
    <div id="thebox" style="display:none;">Content goes here</div>  
     </body>
```

after click of thebutton I want to disable it,but it is not working.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: You have asked a question. So, I don't know if this is the answer: <div id="thebutton" onclick="$(this).addClass('activated')">Click me!</div>

Comment: Woah, somewhat changed the question with the edit haven't we?!?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
$("#thebutton").click(function () {
```

try

```
$("#thebutton").one("click", function () {
```

Comment: note that this only removes the event handler, it doesn't actually "disable" the button

Answer (score 0):

Few things in the code I've spotted for instance when you set the attr('disabled') you are trying to do it to a class of .button instead of the id #button.  And can you actually use the ? : syntax within javascript?

Either way there is a working example for you [here](http://jsbin.com/elopi5/edit)

Answer (score 0):

In your callback use jQuery UI's own internal method to handle disabling the button which will change its decoration.

```
$('#thebutton').click(function () {
    $('#thebutton')
           .toggleClass('activated')
           .button('disable')
           .button('refresh');   // sometimes necessary
});
```